# Getting strings recognized as variable names in R

Tags: r, variables, string-concatenation

Related: [Strings as variable references in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3770589/strings-as-variable-references-in-r)
Possibly related: [Concatenate expressions to subset a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5531238/concatenate-expressions-to-subset-a-dataframe)

---

I've simplified the question per the comment request. Here goes with some example data.

```
dat <- data.frame(num=1:10,sq=(1:10)^2,cu=(1:10)^3)
set1 <- subset(dat,num>5)
set2 <- subset(dat,num<=5)
```

Now, I'd like to make a bubble plot from these. I have a more complicated data set with 3+ colors and complicated subsets, but I do something like this:

```
symbols(set1$sq,set1$cu,circles=set1$num,bg="red")
symbols(set2$sq,set2$cu,circles=set2$num,bg="blue",add=T)
```

I'd like to do a for loop like this:

```
colors <- c("red","blue")
sets <- c("set1","set2")
vars <- c("sq","cu","num")

for (i in 1:length(sets)) {
   symbols(sets[[i]][,sq],sets[[i]][,cu],circles=sets[[i]][,num],
   bg=colors[[i]],add=T)
}
```

I know you can have a variable evaluated to specify the column (like `var="cu"; set1[,var]`; I want to know how to get a variable to specify the data.frame itself (and another to evaluate the column).

---

**Update:** Ran across [this post](http://www.r-bloggers.com/converting-a-string-to-a-variable-name-on-the-fly-and-vice-versa-in-r/) on r-bloggers which has this example:

```
x <- 42
eval(parse(text = "x"))
[1] 42
```

I'm able to do something like this now:

```
eval(parse(text=paste(set[[1]],"$",var1,sep="")))
```

In fiddling with this, I'm finding it interesting that the following are not equivalent:

```
vars <- data.frame("var1","var2")
eval(parse(text=paste(set[[1]],"$",var1,sep="")))
eval(parse(text=paste(set[[1]],"[,vars[[1]]]",sep="")))
```

I actually have to do this:

```
eval(parse(text=paste(set[[1]],"[,as.character(vars[[1]])]",sep="")))
```

**Update2:** The above works to output values... but not in trying to plot. I can't do:

```
for (i in 1:length(set)) {
symbols(eval(parse(text=paste(set[[i]],"$",var1,sep=""))),
       eval(parse(text=paste(set[[i]],"$",var2,sep=""))),
       circles=paste(set[[i]],".","circles",sep=""),
       fg="white",bg=colors[[i]],add=T)
}
```

I get `invalid symbol coordinates`. I checked the class of set[[1]] and it's a factor. If I do `is.numeric(as.numeric(set[[1]]))` I get `TRUE`. Even if I add that above prior to the `eval` statement, I still get the error. Oddly, though, I can do this:

```
set.xvars <- as.numeric(eval(parse(text=paste(set[[i]],"$",var1,sep=""))))
set.yvars <- as.numeric(eval(parse(text=paste(set[[i]],"$",var2,sep=""))))
symbols(xvars,yvars,circles=data$var3)
```

Why different behavior when stored as a variable vs. executed within the symbol function?

Comment: Any chance you could re-write your question with actual questions? There is one in the title but no concise statement of what exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: It would also be very helpful if you gave us some example data with `dput`.

Comment: @Maiasaura: Let me know if my revision is clearer. I reallly don't think data is necessary, but if you really need it I'll figure out some kind of example.

Comment: `var1=42; foo="var1"; get(foo);` is another way to get a variable named after a string.

Comment: @Maiasaura: true, but I want the column of a data frame. I know I can do what you did, but it doesn't work to do `get("data$var1")`.

Comment: does `get("data")[1]`  help? That is, specify the number rather than the name of the column.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get data frame from character variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20498463/get-data-frame-from-character-variable)

Answer (score 55):

You found one answer, i.e. `eval(parse())` .  You can also investigate `do.call()` which is often simpler to implement.  Keep in mind the useful `as.name()`  tool as well, for converting strings to variable names.

Comment: When trying to convert a paste string into a variable, `eval(as.name(paste()))` worked for me, thanks!

Comment: I had a complex structure (a list `myList` of many dataframes called for example `myDF1`, `myDF2`, etc.) and `eval(parse(text=paste0(myList$myDF, "index")))` worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: `eval(as.name(CHARACTER_HERE))` worked for me, hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 42):

The basic answer to the question in the title is `eval(as.symbol(variable_name_as_string))` as Josh O'Brien uses.  e.g.

```
var.name = "x"
assign(var.name, 5)
eval(as.symbol(var.name)) # outputs 5
```

Or more simply:

```
get(var.name) # 5
```

Comment: you deserve a medal. I have tried so many ways to work around this issue and you're telling me there is a function called "get". 7 years later, still helpful!

Answer (score 11):

Without any example data, it really is difficult to know *exactly* what you are wanting. For instance, I can't at all divine what your object `set` (or is it `sets`) looks like.

That said, does the following help at all?

```
set1 <- data.frame(x = 4:6, y = 6:4, z = c(1, 3, 5))

plot(1:10, type="n")
XX <- "set1"
with(eval(as.symbol(XX)), symbols(x, y, circles = z, add=TRUE))
```

---

**EDIT**:

Now that I see your real task, here is a one-liner that'll do everything you want without requiring any `for()` loops:

```
with(dat, symbols(sq, cu, circles = num,
                  bg = c("red", "blue")[(num>5) + 1]))
```

The one bit of code that may feel odd is the bit specifying the background color. Try out these two lines to see how it works:

```
c(TRUE, FALSE) + 1
# [1] 2 1
c("red", "blue")[c(F, F, T, T) + 1]
# [1] "red"  "red"  "blue" "blue"
```

Comment: I added a sample data set for you, but your example works. I was not familiar with the use of `with` -- it seems like it kind of gives a framework for subsequent variable names. I used it successfully like this: `for (i in 1:length(sets)) { with(eval(as.symbol(sets[[i]])), symbols(sq,cu,circles=num,bg=colors[[i]],add=T))` Thanks!

Comment: @Hendy -- Good to hear. I also just added a one-liner which may allow you to make the whole plot without use at all of `subset()` or `for()` loops. Good luck!

Answer (score 9):

If you want to use a string as a variable name, you can use assign:

```
var1="string_name"

assign(var1, c(5,4,5,6,7))

string_name 

[1] 5 4 5 6 7
```

Answer (score 3):

Subsetting the data and combining them back is unnecessary. So are loops since those operations are vectorized. From your previous edit, I'm guessing you are doing all of this to make bubble plots. If that is correct, perhaps the example below will help you. If this is way off, I can just delete the answer.

```
library(ggplot2)
# let's look at the included dataset named trees.
# ?trees for a description
data(trees)
ggplot(trees,aes(Height,Volume)) + geom_point(aes(size=Girth))
# Great, now how do we color the bubbles by groups?
# For this example, I'll divide Volume into three groups: lo, med, high
trees$set[trees$Volume<=22.7]="lo"
trees$set[trees$Volume>22.7 & trees$Volume<=45.4]="med"
trees$set[trees$Volume>45.4]="high"

ggplot(trees,aes(Height,Volume,colour=set)) + geom_point(aes(size=Girth))


# Instead of just circles scaled by Girth, let's also change the symbol
ggplot(trees,aes(Height,Volume,colour=set)) + geom_point(aes(size=Girth,pch=set))

# Now let's choose a specific symbol for each set. Full list of symbols at ?pch
trees$symbol[trees$Volume<=22.7]=1
trees$symbol[trees$Volume>22.7 & trees$Volume<=45.4]=2
trees$symbol[trees$Volume>45.4]=3

ggplot(trees,aes(Height,Volume,colour=set)) + geom_point(aes(size=Girth,pch=symbol))
```

Answer (score 0):

What works best for me is using `quote()` and `eval()` together.

For example, let's print each column using a `for loop`:

```
Columns <- names(dat)
for (i in 1:ncol(dat)){
  dat[, eval(quote(Columns[i]))] %>% print
}
```