# Get data frame from character variable

Tags: r

I pass data frame name as string into a function. How do I get content of referenced data frame from the string? Suppose I have string 'mtcars' and I want to print data frame mtcars:

```
printdf <- function(dataframe) {
  print(dataframe)
}

printdf('mtcars');
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you'll need a `get` in there if the input is a string. Also, depending on your usage of the function, the explicit `print` might not be necessary:

```
printdf <- function(dataframe) {
  get(dataframe)
  # print(get(dataframe))
}
head(printdf("mtcars"))
#                    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
# Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
# Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
# Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
# Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
# Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
```

Comment: To be fair... the explicit print makes sense in a function called 'printdf'

Comment: @Dason, I guess so. But doesn't that interfere with, for example `head`?

Comment: Depends on what the goal is.  I could imagine being frustrated if I wrote a function like this: `blah <- function(df){printdf(df); print("That was my dataframe")}; blah("mtcars")` and if printdf was defined your way I might initially be like "y u no print?"

Comment: The recent edit isn't in line with the output given.