# can't visualize output in Shiny dashboard

Tags: r, shiny, dashboard

I have problems with a schiny dashboard for a university project.

When I start the app it returns the following error:

> "arguments imply differing number of rows: 0.1"

Error that repeats for each output. I can't understand what I did wrong. I am attaching two scripts to the topic: in "global" you find the test datasets and the function to obtain the dtm; in "ui_server" instead the user interface and server is present.

I tested the `dtm` function off the dashboard and it works. I think the problem is in the selection of the input dataframe. I read guides and documentation but I can't understand where the error is, also because everything seems in line with the indications provided by the documentation.

**GENERAL**

```
df1=as.data.frame(cbind(userid=c(1:10), created_at=c(seq(as.Date("2000/1/1"),by= "month", length.out = 10)), 
                    text= c("Abuso sessuale e aggravante dell'uso di sostanze alcoliche", 
                            "Per chi non ricordasse, con l'attuale legge l'accusa di stupro si puÃ² avanzare solamente qualora si possa provare la presenza di violenza. Se la vittima reagisce in modo passivo, senza opporre evidente resistenza, non sussiste stupro, ma abuso sessuale. Insomma, un abominio.", 
                            "@BarbaraDeRossiO Al netto dei titoli sensazionalistici, la CdC ha evidenziato che c'Ã¨ stata violenza sessuale di gruppo con abuso delle condizioni di inferioritÃ  psichica o fisica.  Non ha detto non c'Ã¨ stato stupro perchÃ© la vittima si era ubriacata o la colpa Ã¨ tua perchÃ© avevi bevuto", 
                            "@FiorellaMannoia Cara Fiorella, cito da una mia amica:",
                            "In Manitoba, 6 women were killed",
                            "@FiorellaMannoia Cara Fiorella, cito da una mia amica:", 
                            "@PiovonoRoseNere @Giudo621 Non Ã¨ cosÃ¬ .. lo stupro Ã¨ stato riconosciuto. non Ã¨ stata riconosciuta l'aggravante dell'uso di sostanze alcoliche .. ma la violenza sessuale con l'aggravante dell'abuso di inferioritÃ  psichica proprio perche era ubriaca Ã¨ stato confermato.",
                            "#violenzasessusle #cassazione prima che vi scannia",
                            "@Manu_Erre_ Il punto che Ã¨ un reato specifico, la ",
                            "Si sta scatenando un vortice insulso sulla sentenza")))
df2=as.data.frame(cbind(userid=c(1:7), created_at=c(seq(as.Date("2000/1/1"),by= "month", length.out = 7)), 
                    text= c("@DanielaPF75 @laura_lavespa @chiara84 Se ho ca", 
                            "@salvodimartino6 violenza sessuale di gruppo con abuso condizioni di inferioritÃ  psichica o fisica anche se la vittima ha assunto alcol volontariamente, visto che in uno stato in infermit psichica a prescindere da chi l'abbia determinato,mancano le condizioni per prestare un valido consenso", 
                            "@1511maxi @MustErminea Ascoltami, per tua fortuna", 
                            "La Cassazione (sent. 32462 della III sez. penale) ha ",
                            "Dato che se parla ma nessuno spiega, no, non siamo",
                            "Il reato di violenza sessuale di gruppo con abuso de", 
                            "Quando sale la paura che nostro figlio autistico sia"
                    )))
df3=as.data.frame(cbind(userid=c(1:7), created_at=c(seq(as.Date("2000/1/1"),by= "month", length.out = 7)), 
                    text= c("Abuso sessuale e dinamiche familiari Spesso il luogo", 
                            "Abuso sessuale su una signora cinquantenne durante", 
                            "Ma come fatte a dire che la pedofilia Ã¨ un orientameto", 
                            "Spagna, ragazza violentata da 5 persone. ",
                            "Carica di abuso sessuale di OSU mette in chiaro:",
                            "PerchÃ© non digiunate 10 giorni per ogni abuso sessua", 
                            "La Spagna introduce legge sul consenso esplicito"
                    )))  

datasets<<- list("first dataframe"="df1", 
             "second dataframe"="df2", 
             "third dataframe"="df3" 
             )

getTermMatrix <- memoise(function(dataset) {
users <- dataset[1]
text <- dataset[3]
df_title <- data.frame(doc_id= row.names(users), text= text)
df_title <- remove_empty(df_title, which = "rows")
corpus <- Corpus(DataframeSource(df_title))
removeap <- function(x) gsub("'", " ", x)
removeNumPunct <- function(x) gsub("[^[:alpha:][:space:][:cntrl:][:alnum:][:blank:]?&/\\-]*", "", x)
removeURL <- function(x) gsub(" ?(f, ht)(tp)(s?)(://)(.*)[., /](.*)", "", x)
removeshorturl <- function(x) gsub("[goo.\\S+][@\\S+][ow.ly\\S+][ow.ly\\S+][bit.ly\\S+][fb.\\S+]
                               [pic.\\S+][\\S+\\.it\\S+][\\S+\\.com\\S+]", "", x)
corpus=tm_map(corpus, content_transformer(removeap))
corpus=tm_map(corpus, content_transformer(removeURL))
corpus=tm_map(corpus, content_transformer(removeshorturl))
corpus=tm_map(corpus, content_transformer(removeNumPunct))
corpus=tm_map(corpus, removeWords, stopwords("it"))
ds0 <- tm_map(corpus,content_transformer(tolower))
ds1 <- tm_map(ds0,removeNumbers)
ds <- tm_map(ds1, removeWords, c ("nulla", "pare", "niente", "nessuno", "nessuna", "meno", "https", "cosÃ", "giÃ", "enne"))
dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(ds, control = list(removePunctuation = TRUE, stopwords = "it"))
})
```

**UI AND SERVER**

```
ui <- fluidPage(titlePanel("IULM Dashboard"), sidebarLayout(sidebarPanel(
selectInput("dataset", "Choose a Dataset:",
          choices = datasets), actionButton("update", "Change")

)   
,

mainPanel(  
plotOutput(outputId = "wordcloud", width = 600, height = 600),
tableOutput(outputId = "latenttopics")
)   
)   
)

server <- function(input, output){

datasetInput <- reactive({

input$update

isolate({
  withProgress({
    setProgress(message = "Processing corpus...")
    getTermMatrix(input$dataset)
  })
  })
  })

output$wordcloud <- renderPlot({
v=datasetInput()
dtm1 = removeSparseTerms(v, 0.992)
rowTotals <- apply(dtm1 , 1, sum) 
dtm2   <- dtm1[rowTotals> 0, ]
wdtm <- weightTf(dtm2)
freq <- colSums(as.matrix(wdtm))
wf = data.frame(term = names(freq), occurrences = freq)
wc <- as.matrix(weightTf(wf[1]))
wordcloud(wc, freq = wf$occurrences, max.words= 50, scale = c(10,1), random.color= TRUE, random.order= FALSE, 
          rot.per= 0.35, colors= brewer.pal(8, "Dark2"))
 })



output$latenttopics <- renderTable({
v=datasetInput()
burnin <- 4000
iter <- 2000
thin <- 500
seed <-list(2003,5,63,100001,765)
nstart <- 5
best <- TRUE
k <- 5
dtm1 = removeSparseTerms(v, 0.992)
rowTotals <- apply(dtm1 , 1, sum) 
dtm2   <- dtm1[rowTotals> 0, ]
ldaOut <- LDA(dtm2, k=k, method= "Gibbs")
ldaOut.terms.top10 <- as.data.frame(terms(ldaOut,10))
ldaOut.terms.top10}

)

}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is in `getTermMatrix` function:

```
getTermMatrix <- memoise(function(dataset) {
  users <- dataset[1]
  text <- dataset[3]
  ...
```

You pass in a string based on the selection of `input$dataset`. If `first dataframe` is selected, then the *string* `"df1"` is passed to `getTermMatrix`. What you want, however, is the actual *data frame* `df1` defined earlier.

There are a number of approaches to considering a variable or data frame from a string, for reference:

[Get data frame from character variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20498463/get-data-frame-from-character-variable)

[Getting strings recognized as variable names in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9057006/getting-strings-recognized-as-variable-names-in-r)

You can try the following which should work:

```
users <- get(dataset)[1]
text <- get(dataset)[3]
```

Please let me know if this helps.

Comment: Great! It works! thank you so much! Now i have a little problem with text encoding… i will search some solutions in the community