# R - Reading vector or dataframe from string

Tags: r, vector, dataframe

I would like to read a data frame from a string. It is a bit difficult to explain, and, so far I couldn't find the answer anywhere.

Let's imagine I have several data frames: "Param1", "Param2", ... "Param100". I would like to be able to access them from a for loop:

```
for (i in c(1:100)){
  a <- paste0("Param",i)
  b <- ??? (a)
}
```

Where `b` would become "Param1", ... "Param100" when `i` varies from 1 to 100.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9057006/getting-strings-recognized-as-variable-names-in-r

Comment: Try just `b <- mget(ls(pattern = paste0("Param", 1:100)))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `get`.

```
for (i in 1:100) {
  b <- get(paste0("Param", i))
}
```

Comment: Cant you just use `mget` without a loop?

Comment: Yes, you could. `mget(paste0("Param", 1:100))` I believe would work. You'll end up with a list to operate on.

Comment: More like `mget(ls(pattern = paste0("Param", 1:100)))`

Comment: Oops, thanks David. I've fixed my comment of a bug. Its a bit easier than your suggestion though, the `ls` part isn't necessary I think.

Comment: I think it is necessary.

Comment: Oh, right because there is no regex involved. It would be necessary for more general lookups.