# in R, how can I read variable's value with variable's name as a string?

Tags: r

I have an object that contains the name of a variable as a string
example :

```
OBJECT_containing_variables_name <- "the_variable_I_want_to_read"
```

Is there a function I can use to read `the_variable_I_want_to_read`  using the `OBJECT_containing_variables_name` as a string?

---

---

In fact, I am trying to make a for loop, and I construct the name of my variable with

```
paste0("tablename$",eval(parse(text= "colnames_as_string[i]")))
```

This actually retuns the name of my variable as a string like `"tablename$colname"`

But I want to actually read the variable itself. 
How can I do this ?

**I made some tests :**

- I already tried eval and parse functions like :

  ```
  eval(  paste0("tablename$",eval(parse(text="colnames_as_string[i]"))) )
  ```

but it also returns the name of the variable as a string

- I also tried :

  ```
  eval(parse(text=" paste0("tablename$",eval(parse(text="colnames_as_string[i]")))  "))
  ```

but it still returns the name of the variable as a string.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18222286/dynamically-select-data-frame-columns-using-and-a-vector-of-column-names may be useful

Comment: `eval(parse(text =paste0("tablename$",eval(parse(text= "colnames_as_string[i]")))))` should work. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9057006/getting-strings-recognized-as-variable-names-in-r

Comment: This is atrocious code. If you get into the habit of writing code with `eval(parse())` you will regret that sooner or later. My guess is that you should simply do `tablename[[colnames_as_string[i]]]`.

Comment: @Roland Your code works perfectly for me !! And yes, it is much easier. Thank you very much

Comment: Add the solution as an answer and mark it correct instead of adding '#solved' to the title

Answer (score 0):

Too long to paste as a comment, so an answer instead. If you're using `data.frame` and want to retrieve a column given the column name is stored as vector (`k`, say), here's what you can do:

```
> w <- as.data.frame(mtcars)
> k <- colnames(w)[1:5]
> k
[1] "mpg"  "cyl"  "disp" "hp"   "drat"
> w[, k[1]]
 [1] 21.0 21.0 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 17.8 16.4 17.3 15.2 10.4 10.4 14.7
[18] 32.4 30.4 33.9 21.5 15.5 15.2 13.3 19.2 27.3 26.0 30.4 15.8 19.7 15.0 21.4
> w$mpg
 [1] 21.0 21.0 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 17.8 16.4 17.3 15.2 10.4 10.4 14.7
[18] 32.4 30.4 33.9 21.5 15.5 15.2 13.3 19.2 27.3 26.0 30.4 15.8 19.7 15.0 21.4
```

In a loop this could be achieved using the `apply` family of functions:

```
# Testing just one column 
> paste(w[, k[1]], collapse = " ")
[1] "21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 17.8 16.4 17.3 15.2 10.4 10.4 14.7 32.4 30.4 33.9 21.5 15.5 15.2 13.3 19.2 27.3 26 30.4 15.8 19.7 15 21.4"

# Using sapply to get a vector with all column names in 'k'
> sapply(k, function(z) paste(w[, z], collapse = " "))
                                                                                                                                                        mpg 
  "21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 17.8 16.4 17.3 15.2 10.4 10.4 14.7 32.4 30.4 33.9 21.5 15.5 15.2 13.3 19.2 27.3 26 30.4 15.8 19.7 15 21.4" 
                                                                                                                                                        cyl 
                                                                                          "6 6 4 6 8 6 8 4 4 6 6 8 8 8 8 8 8 4 4 4 4 8 8 8 8 4 4 4 8 6 8 4" 
                                                                                                                                                       disp 
     "160 160 108 258 360 225 360 146.7 140.8 167.6 167.6 275.8 275.8 275.8 472 460 440 78.7 75.7 71.1 120.1 318 304 350 400 79 120.3 95.1 351 145 301 121" 
                                                                                                                                                         hp 
                                   "110 110 93 110 175 105 245 62 95 123 123 180 180 180 205 215 230 66 52 65 97 150 150 245 175 66 91 113 264 175 335 109" 
                                                                                                                                                       drat 
"3.9 3.9 3.85 3.08 3.15 2.76 3.21 3.69 3.92 3.92 3.92 3.07 3.07 3.07 2.93 3 3.23 4.08 4.93 4.22 3.7 2.76 3.15 3.73 3.08 4.08 4.43 3.77 4.22 3.62 3.54 4.11"
```