# R: Concatenate variable name and use it

Tags: r, concatenation

I try to concatenate a variable name by a string and a variable value to call an existing variable which I can use in further procedures, f.e.

```
var_pre23 <- "it works" # existing variable

var_pre <- "var_pre"
var_add <- 23
var_comb <- paste0 (var_pre, var_add) # results in "var_pre23"

print (var_comb) # this should lead to printing "it works"
```

I want to concatenate "var_add" and "var_pre" to a variable "var_pre23". The real variable "var_pre23" already exists and has the value "it works".
So in the end I want to use

```
print(var_comb)
```

and receive the value "it works".

I know that from other script languages - as far as I remember in PHP it works like

```
echo ${"var_pre23"} or ${$var_pre.$var_add}
```

I think I only need a specific command for that.

Thank you!!

Comment: [Getting strings recognized as variable names in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9057006/getting-strings-recognized-as-variable-names-in-r)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the function get to obtain the value :

```
var_pre23 <- "it works" 
var_pre <- "var_pre"
var_add <- 23
var_comb <- get(paste0(var_pre, var_add)) 

print(var_comb)
```

Comment: I just now posted the solution I found (sorry, I didn't see that you also answered)
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much - I used the following code, that worked:

```
var_comb <- eval(parse(text = paste0 (var_pre, var_add)))
```

Bye