# Use index variable in a for loop as a column name within Dplyr's summarize function in R

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr, statistics

**Issue:**
I'm having trouble getting Dplyr's summarize function to recognize that the index variable is a column name.

```
for (i in colnames(df)){
    temp_frame <- df%>%
      select(group, i)%>%
      group_by(group)%>%
      summarize(yes = sum(i == "1"), no = sum(i=="0"))
}
```

**Full project:**
I have a data frame of variables I'm attempting run stats on. Because it's so long, I'm trying to create a for loop that takes the independent variable column (group) and each dependent variable column and creates a bunch of tables that are properly formatted to run a fisher's exact test on. Without a for loop, the code for the fisher's exact runs perfectly, but once I try to make the tables in the for loop the summarize function doesn't seem to understand that i is a column name within the temp_frame.

Here's the full code with some stand-in original data

```
#create starting data frame
df <- data.frame(
  group= c("control", "control", "control", "experimental", "experimental", "experimental"),
  a = c(1,0,1,1,1,0),
  b = c(0,1,0,0,1,1)
)

#create empty stats data frame
stats <- data.frame(name = "", fish="")

for (i in colnames(df)){
  if (i == group){ #skip over the "group" column to avoid trying to make a group vs group test
    next
  } else{
    temp_frame <- df%>%
      select(group, i)%>%
      group_by(group)%>%
      summarize(yes = sum(i == "1"), no = sum(i=="0"))%>% 
      select(-group)
    
    stats[nrow(stats) + 1,] = c(i, fisher.test(temp_frame)$p.value) # add each p value to the stats data frame

  }
}
```

Outside of the for loop, were I to just specify the a column in the summarize function, the temp_frame would first look like this, which is exactly what I want:

| yes | no |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |

but instead, I'm just getting

| yes | no |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 |

I think it's because it's not recognizing that a is a column name and instead, just giving me the output as if a was a string.

How do I tell it that i represents a column name within the temp_frame df?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out!

Within the for loop, I added a temporary column to the original df that matched the loop variable's column and then used that temporary column instead of i in the dplyr functions.

```
for (i in colnames(df)){
  if (i == group){
    next
  } else{
df$temp_column <- df[,which(colnames(df)==i)]
    temp_frame <- df%>%
      select(group, temp_column)%>%
      group_by(group)%>%
      summarize(yes = sum(temp_column == "1"), no = sum(temp_column=="0"))%>% 
      select(-group)
    
    stats[nrow(stats) + 1,] = c(i, fisher.test(temp_frame)$p.value)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For sure there migth be a better solution which does not involve a `for` loop, and some other users will certainly find a way to do this using dplyr verbs like `across`.

But I appreciate you found a solution that works, and I want to focus on your code.

The key point was to use `eval(as.symbol(i))`. I got it from a post here called [Getting strings recognized as variable names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9057006/getting-strings-recognized-as-variable-names-in-r), which describes your problem accurately.

The combination of base R with tidyverse is sometimes tricky. For example, I had to add some "" to "group" in the `if` statement.

Something else is that I replaced the `==` operators, which only work element wise and are not useful when you want to scan a whole column. Use `%in%` instead.

Also I removed the obsolete `select` before the `group_by`.

```
#create starting data frame
df <- data.frame(
  group= c("control", "control", "control", "experimental", "experimental", "experimental"),
  a = c(1,0,1,1,1,0),
  b = c(0,1,0,0,1,1)
)

#create empty stats data frame
stats <- data.frame(name = "", fish="")

for (i in colnames(df)){
  if (i == "group"){ 
    #skip over the "group" column to avoid trying to make a group vs group test
    next
  } else{
    temp_frame <- df %>%
      group_by(group) %>% 
      summarise(yes = sum(eval(as.symbol(i)) %in% 1),
                no  = sum(eval(as.symbol(i)) %in% 0)) %>%
      select(-group)
    
    stats[nrow(stats) + 1,] = c(i, fisher.test(temp_frame)$p.value) 
    # add each p value to the stats data frame
    
  }
}
```

Output for i = "b"

```
> temp_frame
# A tibble: 2 × 2
    yes    no
  <int> <int>
1     1     2
2     2     1
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is great! Thank you so much. I only saw your comment after posting a different solution that I'd found, but I really appreciate you taking the time to lend me a hand! I'm also really grateful that you willing to find a solution that built on what I already had. Thanks again! Have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to share my progress to a dplyr solution with you.

I reorganised the data to a longer and tidier format. The thought behind this was that for computations across rows instead of columns, there is `group_by` which makes everything easier.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(
  group= c("control", "control", "control", "experimental", "experimental", "experimental"),
  a = c(1,0,1,1,1,0),
  b = c(0,1,0,0,1,1)
)

df2 <- df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = !group) %>%
  group_by(group, name) %>%
  summarise(yes = sum(value),
            no = n()-sum(value))
```

This is how it looks like:

```
> df2
# A tibble: 4 × 4
# Groups:   group [2]
  group        name    yes    no
  <chr>        <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 control      a         2     1
2 control      b         1     2
3 experimental a         2     1
4 experimental b         2     1
```

However, I was unable to implement `fisher.test` in the pipeline. If you have any suggestions, maybe using the fact that it also can take two factors, I would be glad to hear them.

```
gr <- df2 %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  group_split()

fish <- function(x){
  temp <- data.frame(gr[[x]])
  temp$p.value <- fisher.test(gr[[x]][3:4])$p.value
  return(temp)
}

results <- rbind(fish(1),(fish(2)))
```

```
> results
         group name yes no p.value
1      control    a   1  1       1
2      control    b   1  2       1
3 experimental    a   2  1       1
4 experimental    b   2  1       1
```