# ggplot multiple dataframes in R using lapply whilst specifying column names in function call

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to apply the following ggplot function to a list of dataframes, each with the exact same format. This is the format of the data:

[image]

All datasets have same datatypes, column names, and row & column lengths. For each list of dataframes, I want to always plot xvar as Time, and yvar as Zscore.

The function I want to use is as follows.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

Tzero = 0 
Tminus120 = -120
TEnd = 120

testIDplot <- function(data1,
                          xvar,
                          yvar){ggplot(data = data1)+
    geom_line(aes(x={{xvar}},y={{yvar}}),colour="#fd8d3c", size=0.5) +
    geom_vline(xintercept=Tzero, colour="black", size=0.8)+
    labs(x = "Time (s)", y = "Z-Score")+
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(Tminus120,TEnd,60), limits = c(Tminus120,NA))+ 
    scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), limits = c(-3, 6))}
```

To call this function normally, I would specify
`testIDplot(newdata,Time,Zscore)`

However, I don't know how to specify the columns when calling through a list. I tried lapply:

```
listofDF <- list(newdata1,newdata2,newdata3,newdata4,newdata5)
plotlist <- lapply(listofDF,testIDplot)
plotlist[1]
```

But this method doesn't work because of the missing aesthetics x and y.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Try with `lapply(listofDF, \(x) testIDplot(x, Time, Zscore))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass these values in the `...` space of `lapply`:

```r
library(tidyverse)


dfs <- map(1:4, \(x) {
  tibble(
    a = letters,
    b = runif(26, 1, 10)
  )
})

plot_df <- function(df, xvar, yvar) {
  
  ggplot(df, aes({{xvar}}, {{yvar}})) +
    geom_col()
  
}

# Testing function call for one dataset:
plot_df(dfs[[1]], a, b)
```

[image]

```r
# Pass column names after the function argument in `lapply`
# (either as positional, or preferably named arguments)
lapply(dfs, plot_df, xvar = a, yvar = b)
```

Anonymous functions are a super-helpful and clear way as well, as suggested by Stefan above:

```r
lapply(dfs, \(df) plot_df(df, xvar = a, yvar = b))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could potentially try the following, change: `aes(x={{xvar}},y={{yvar}}` -> `x=eval(parse(xvar)), y = eval(parse(var))`

Then:

```
lapply(listofDF, testIDplot, xvar = "Time", y = "Score".
```

[see this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9057006/getting-strings-recognized-as-variable-names-in-r)

Or try this:

```
aes(x= .data[[x_var]], y= .data[[y_var]])
```

[this other solution](https://community.rstudio.com/t/string-as-column-name-in-ggplot/155588/2)

Hope this might help.